# How to use Freebase's suggestion script from a userscript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, freebase, scriptish

I want to write a (Scriptish) userscript to include among other things [the Freebase suggestion search widget](http://www.freebase.com/docs/suggest) on various web sites. I've tried several approaches to get this to work but no luck so far.

My userscript looks like (take note of the wildcard inclusion):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id             meta@parsed.nl
// @name           Meta
// @version        1.0
// @namespace      
// @author         
// @description    
// @include        *
// @run-at         document-end
// @require        https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js
// @require        http://freebaselibs.com/static/suggest/1.3/suggest.min.js
// @noframes
// ==/UserScript==

$("head").append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://freebaselibs.com/static/suggest/1.3/suggest.min.css" />');
$("body").prepend('<input id="freebase-suggest" type="text"/>');

$("#freebase-suggest")
    .suggest()
    .bind("fb-select", function(e, data) {
        alert("");
    });
```

Everything loads fine but when I try to use the search box it doesn't work and the following error is displayed in the error console:

> Error: jQuery16101843227533633628_1325186688691 is not defined Source
>   File:
>   http://www.freebase.com/private/suggest?callback=jQuery16101843227533633628_1325186688691&prefix=ron+paul&type_strict=any&all_types=false
>   Line: 1

Apparently the script is using JSONP for cross domain requests and my gut feeling is telling me the callback `jQuery16101843227533633628_1325186688691` is being defined in a different context from the document the widget is in (the Scriptish context versus unsafeWindow).

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding both jQuery and the Freebase suggest script in the DOM and waiting for them to load is enough to make this work. But you do have to reference `unsafeWindow`.

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

// Only add jQuery if the site doesn't have it already (to prevent conflicts)
if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery === "undefined") {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js';
    head.appendChild(script);
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://freebaselibs.com/static/suggest/1.3/suggest.min.js';
head.appendChild(script);

window.setTimeout(function() { 
    $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;

    $("head").append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://freebaselibs.com/static/suggest/1.3/suggest.min.css" />');
    $("body").prepend('<input id="freebase-suggest" type="text"/>');

    $("#freebase-suggest")
        .suggest()
        .bind("fb-select", function(e, data) {
            alert("");
        });

}, 1000);
```

I don't know if this approach is smart, but it does work.